# Springboot Webclient throws readtimeout errors

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Spring Webclient throws lot of read timeouts (on load of 1000 requests per second). I am using Springboot version 2.1.1.RELEASE. Please find the code below and if I am missing any configuration, let me know:

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder().build();
}

public Mono<String> post(String url, JSONObject body) {

    Mono<String> result = webClient.post().uri(url)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
            .exchange()
            .flatMap { clientResponse ->
        return handleResponse(clientResponse)
    }
    return result;
}

private Mono<String> handleResponse(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
         if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError() || clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .flatMap { errorBody ->
                return Mono.error(new CustomException(errorBody, clientResponse.statusCode().value()))
            }
        } else {
            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? Did you configure a timeout for the client? Could you share a stacktrace of the error? When requesting the remote service with JMeter, what kind of max latency are you getting?

Comment: @BrianClozel `@Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 30000)
                .doOnConnected { connection ->
            connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5))
                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(30))
        }
        ReactorClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient));

        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(httpConnector)
                .build();
    }`

Comment: @BrianClozel I tried above timeout configuration as well as default `WebClient.builder().build();`. In both cases, I am getting readtimeout exception

Comment: Could you add a « log() » operator after the exchange and report back here with the logs?

Comment: @BrianClozel `Pooled connection observed an error
2018-12-17T18:13:36.903185649Z io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null` This is the error log I am getting.

Comment: I was asking about `log()` operators mainly. Could you add one after `exchange()` and another one after `bodyToMono` and share the logs?

Comment: @BrianClozel Sorry I am not sure how to add that.. do you have a sample?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bclozel/5d3f0475953edd54af773e211ea7de10

Comment: `13:55:50.287 [reactor-http-nio-6] INFO  reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.49127 - | request(unbounded)
13:55:50.288 [reactor-http-nio-6] INFO  reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.48910 - onComplete()
13:55:50.310 [reactor-http-nio-6] ERROR r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0xa1c67a8f, L:/10.253.8.138:55671 - REMOTEhOST:PORT] Pooled connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null`

Comment: `13:55:50.312 [reactor-http-nio-6] ERROR reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.48759 - onError(io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException)
13:55:50.312 [reactor-http-nio-6] ERROR reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.48759 - 
io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null`

Comment: @BrianClozel I have added comment in your github. please take a look

Comment: @BrianClozel When the server is idle with no requests for sometime and then try to send a request, it throws Readtimeout very first time. Do you see any problem?

Comment: No. At that point, a small project reproducing the problem and joining the gitter.im channel, or creating an issue on jira.spring.io for the Spring Framework is your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said [on the Spring Framework issue you've opened](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17610) (thanks for that!), this doesn't seem to be a bug in Framework.

The confusion comes from the fact that when running multiple web client requests concurrently and adding the `log` operator on the reactive pipeline to get more information, the logs make you think that the read timeout is triggered even though the request was just made.

If I remember correctly, the suffix number you're seeing in the logs like `reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.48759` is tied to the subscriber.

In your case, this means that

```
13:55:50.287 [reactor-http-nio-6] INFO reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.49127 - | request(unbounded)
```

and

```
13:55:50.312 [reactor-http-nio-6] ERROR reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.48759 - onError(
```

are not about the same HTTP requests. Reactor is scheduling tasks on worker threads, so when you're seeing things happening sequentially on the same thread, it doesn't mean those units of work are being done for the same subscriber.

If you follow the subscriber id in the logs, you should see that the amount of time between requesting the data and not getting is about 5 seconds.

Not on that last point, I've created a Reactor HTTP server that sends the response body after 10 seconds:

```
HttpServer.create().host("localhost").port(8080).handle((req, res) -> {
    return res.sendString(Flux.just("Hello")
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(10)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}).bindNow().onDispose().block();
```

And a WebClient that fetches this data:

```
String response = WebClient.create().get().uri("http://localhost:8080/")
    .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).log().block();
System.out.println(response);
```

I'm not getting any read timeout. So something in your application must be configuring such a timeout.